# Node.Js Cannot find module, module.js:471

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started learning node.js today. I just downloaded the most recent version. I have run into several issues along the way but i was able to solved most of them besides one error which I keep getting:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Dennis\sample.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

This is my code, a sample js code I got from W3schools.

```
<script>
    var http = require('http');

    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);

</script>
```

My nodejs folder is in C:\Program Files\nodejs.
I put this sample.js file inside the folder and I had no luck. I even copy this sample file and put it under all the path from C to nodejs, still nothing.

Any tip will be appreciated.

Comment: get rid of the script tags, those are only valid if you're working inside an html file.

Comment: and yes, it has to be a .js file

Comment: @Abhijeet For the record, *no* the file name does not need to end with `.js` for node to interpret it. Try it yourself. What does happen is that `require()` statements that ask for a file and do not specify an extension will default to a file of the same name that ends with `.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure even w3Schools wouldn't put *that* in their tutorials.

Your file should contain only:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

`<script>` tags belong in html pages (or templates, etc.).

Also, no the file name does not need to end with `.js` for node to interpret it. What does happen is that `require()` statements that ask for a file and do not specify an extension will default to a file of the same name that ends with `.js`.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have get rid of that. but the error persists. I have replaced the js file in the path C:\Users\Dennis\. Does it have to do the fact that sample.js is a txt file? I simply put these codes into a empty txt file.

Comment: Yes, it has to be a .js file

Comment: I have converted it as a js file, and it is not outputing anything. when I do node new.js there is a window poped up asking for my permission,and I clicked yes, and then nothing happens in the command prompt, just the cursor moved to the new line and the title changed from "Node.js command prompt" to "new.js". Do you have any insignt into this? thanks!

Comment: @Abhijeet For the record, *no* the file name does not need to end with `.js` for node to interpret it. Try it yourself. What does happen is that `require()` statements that ask for a file and do not specify an extension will default to a file of the same name that ends with `.js`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run in console, for example I have linux and run in console:

## nodejs nombre.js

where nombre.js

var http = require('http');

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World!');
```

}).listen(8080);

then , so I check with

## netstat -an

tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN